# decomposition of ellipse to triangles with openGL (c++)

Tags: c++, opengl, drawing, draw, freeglut

I have to do my homework (draw a butterfly in OpenGL) for university. Currently I'm working on the body of the butterfly, which is a simple ellipse (it will be a 2D game). I have to draw this filled ellipse with triangles, because we mustn't use other libraries (I assume there's a simple Circle() or something like that function).

Now I'm able to draw a triangle, but creating a Triangle from the butterfly's body's class don't work. Here is the code:

```
class Triangle {
    unsigned int vao;
    unsigned int vbo[2];
    float phi;
    float vertexCoords[6];
    float vertexColors[9] = {1,0,0, 0,1,0,  0,0,1};

public:

    Triangle(float x1,float y1,float x2,float y2,float x3, float y3) {
        vertexCoords[0] = x1;
        vertexCoords[1] = y1;
        vertexCoords[2] = x2;
        vertexCoords[3] = y2;
        vertexCoords[4] = x3;
        vertexCoords[5] = y3;
        Animate(0);
    }

    void setTriangleColor(float r, float g, float b) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i+=3) {
            vertexColors[i] = r;
            vertexColors[i + 1] = g;
            vertexColors[i + 2] = b;        
        }
        Create();
    }

    void setPointColor(float r, float g, float b, int count) {
        vertexColors[count * 3] = r;
        vertexColors[count * 3 + 1] = g;
        vertexColors[count * 3 + 2] = b;
        Create();
    }

    void Create() { 
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glGenBuffers(2, &vbo[0]);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(vertexCoords),vertexCoords,GL_STATIC_DRAW);  
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0,2, GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0, NULL);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexColors), vertexColors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
    }

    void Animate(float t) { /*phi = t;*/ phi = 0; }

    void Draw() {
        mat4 ScaleSmaller(
            0.01, 0   , 0   , 0,
            0  , 0.01 , 0   , 0,
            0  , 0   , 0.01 , 0,
            0  , 0   , 0   , 1
        );
        mat4 MVPTransform1(1, 0, 0, 0,
            0, cosf(phi), -sinf(phi), 0,
            0, sinf(phi), cosf(phi), 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1);
        int location = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "MVP");
        if (location >= 0) glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, GL_TRUE, (MVPTransform1*ScaleSmaller)); 
        else printf("uniform MVP cannot be set\n");

        glBindVertexArray(vao); 
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    }
};

struct Point {
    float x, y;

    Point(float x,float y):x(x),y(y){}
    Point():x(0),y(0){}
};

class MyEllipse {   
    float width;
    float height;
    Point origo;
    std::vector<Triangle> triangles = std::vector<Triangle>();

public:
    MyEllipse() {}

    MyEllipse(Point origo,float width, float height):origo(origo),width(width),height(height) {
        float px = origo.x + (width / 2) * cosf(90);
        float py = origo.y + (height / 2) * cosf(90);
        float prevX = origo.x + (width / 2) * cosf(0);
        float prevY = origo.y + (height / 2) * cosf(0);
        Triangle elem1(origo.x, origo.y, px, py, prevX, prevY);
        triangles.push_back(elem1);
    }

    void Create() {
        for (Triangle value : triangles) {
            value.Create();
        }
    }

    void Draw() {
        for (Triangle value : triangles) {
            value.Draw();
        }
    }
};
```

In the code I create a Triangle and a MyEllipse with the same parameters in the same location.

```
float px = 10 + (50 / 2) * cosf(90);
float py = 10 + (50 / 2) * cosf(90);
float prevX = 10 + (50 / 2) * cosf(0);
float prevY = 10 + (50 / 2) * cosf(0);

Triangle triangle(10, 0, px, py, prevX, prevY);
MyEllipse test1 = MyEllipse(Point(10, 0), 50, 50);
```

(Later I'll add more triangles to the vector, now I'M just testing.) The problem, that I can see the triangle, but in case that I delete the triangle create line, I don't see anything. I didn't forget to add the appropriate Draw() and Create() function calls, in the other part of the code, when I call triangle.Create() or triangle.Draw(), immediately after that I call the test1.Create() and test1.Draw() functions.

Can anybody tell me anything about this issue, because I'm afraid I have no idea to solve the issue.

Comment: cosf will most likely take radians, not degree, so passing 90 looks wrong.

Comment: Just for the records: Creating a vao/vbo for each triangle is not the intended way of using modern opengl. Create one VBO for all positions of all triangles and so on. Then draw them all at once.

Comment: I'll try with radian numbers, but the problem, that I'm using cosf() when I create directly the Triangle class and it is visible.

Comment: The trick is `for (Triangle &value : triangles)`, focus on `&`! (Create in `Create`).

Comment: Did you modify both loops? In Create and in Draw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the methodes `MyEllipse::Create` and `MyEllipse ::Draw` a copy of each triangle is created when the triangles are iterated:

```
for (Triangle value : triangles) // <- the "content" of "triangles" is copied to "value"
{
    value.Create();
}
```

You have to use a reference to the triangles in the container

```
for (Triangle &value : triangles) {
    .....
}
```

Further [`cos`, `cosf`, `cosl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/cos) computes the cosine of arg, measured in radians.

This means you have to use

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>

float angle_in_degree = ....;
cosf(angle_in_degree * M_PI/180.0f);
```

If you can't see the triangles, then this may be the case, because 2 points of the triangle are almost identical. Change the polygon mode, to draw lines instead of polygons (**for debug reason only**):

```
glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE ); 
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

**But creating separate vertex buffers and vertex array objects for each triangle is a very bad idea. Create one vertex buffer and one vertex array object for the mesh.**

I recommend to create the vertex buffer and the vertex array object somehow like this:

```
float a = 0.2f;
float b = 0.5f;
int   no_of_triangles = 20;
std::vector<float> varray{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f };
for ( int i = 0; i <= no_of_triangles; ++i )
{
    float angle = (float)i/(float)no_of_triangles * 2.0f * M_PI;
    float x     = cos( angle );
    float y     = sin( angle );
    varray.push_back( x * a );
    varray.push_back( y * b );
    varray.push_back( 0.5f - x * 0.5f );
    varray.push_back( 0.5f - y * 0.5f );
    varray.push_back( (0.5f*x+0.5f)*(0.5f*y+0.5f) );
}

GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers( 1, &vbo );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo );
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, varray.size()*sizeof(*varray.data()), varray.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW );

GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
glBindVertexArray( vao );
glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5*sizeof(*varray.data()), 0 );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
glVertexAttribPointer( 1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5*sizeof(*varray.data()), (void*)(2*sizeof(*varray.data())) );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 1 );

glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
glBindVertexArray( 0 );
```

Since the vertex buffer contains the center point and a list of the points around the ellipse, the mesh can be drawn by the primitive type `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`:

```
glBindVertexArray( vao );
glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, (GLsizei)varray.size()/5 );
glBindVertexArray( 0 );
```

Preview:

[image]

Comment: yep, that's it!!! The last one was the key, which helped me to solve this, finally!!!! Thanks a lot, I'm your dept! he problem was with the coordinates, if you see I've calculated all the coordinates with a cos() function and as a result the coords were almost identical! Furthermore, yes I've to change to itereator stuffs to reference!  Really thanks for all of you!